# truffle-hdwallet-provider web3.eth.getaccounts unhandledpromiserejectionwarning invalid JSON request

Tags: json, web3js, truffle

I have the following code. However, it's failing on the web3.eth.getAccounts call.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
  process.env.MNEMONIC,
  process.env.PROVIDER_URI
);

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log);
```

I am getting the following error. Does anyone have any idea why?

> (node:16822) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: invalid json request
> at /node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider/dist/index.js:15:620862  at e.i.onreadystatechange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, you can try to use web3@1.0.0-beta.37 and truffle-hdwallet-provider@1.0.5 to bypass it for now.

[Github issue](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/2447)